# Word VBA Range.Find object works incorrectly

Tags: vba, debugging, ms-word, find, range

I found an interesting thing:

In word 2010, select some text, and run the following VBA code:

```
public Sub Test()
    With Selection.Range.Find
        MsgBox .Execute(Selection.Range.text) 
        MsgBox .Found
    End With
End Sub
```

Both the two message box say "False", but both should be "True". Why?

Answer (score 0):

**Very interesting!**

Word 2007 exhibits the same behaviour.

The curious thing is that this not only when you are searching from VBA: If you select some text in the doc and press "find", the find dialog displays as default the selected text as objective.
By pressing "Find Next >" Word displays an error message **"Word has reached the end of the document ... etc".**

This doesn't happen if you modify the text to search deleting the last character.  VBA is consistent with that: the folowing code works!

```
Sub tt()
    With Selection.Range.Find    
       MsgBox .Execute(Mid(Selection.Range.Text,1,Len(Selection.Range.Text)-1))  
       MsgBox .Found  
    End With  
End Sub
```

Not solved ... but proved to be consistent with the GUI.

HTH!